# Deixar o número negativo em vermelho no JS

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo deixar número em vermelho quando ele fica negativo no contador, como devo escrever meu script?

```js
var currentNumberWhapper = document.getElementById('currentNumber');
var currentNumber = 0;

function incremento() {
     currentNumber = currentNumber + 1
     currentNumberWhapper.innerHTML = currentNumber
}

function decremento() {
     currentNumber = currentNumber - 1
     currentNumberWhapper.innerHTML = currentNumber

     if (currentNumberWhapper < 0) {
          document.getElementById('currentNumber').style.color = "red"
     } else {
          document.getElementById('currentNumber').style.color = "black"
     }
}
```

```html
<body>

     <h1>Contador</h1>
     <p>Clique nos botões para alterar o valor.</p>

     <div class="contador">
         <button name="adicionar" onclick="incremento()">+</button>
                <p id="currentNumber">0</p> 
         <button name="subtrair" onclick="decremento()">-</button>
     </div>
     <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: pq não compara diretamente com a variável ?`if (currentNumber < 0) {`    também  pq fazer o `getElementById` se já tem uma variável com o elemento ? pode fazer `currentNumberWhapper.style.color =....`  por fim, no lugar de trocar o atributo "color" seria melhor muda o style do elemento "p", estude como adicionar e remover classes, tem vários exemplos aqui no site :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual currentNumber é um objeto

Comment: @CmteCardeal olha no código: `var currentNumber = 0;` acho que não é um objeto, vc não se confundiu?

Comment: @RicardoPontual de fato. `currentNumberWhapper`, ele poderia usar `textContent` para se basear nos valores e assim fazer toda a lógica, sem precisar do `currentNumber `

Comment: Só como referência: https://pastebin.com/uSAjY76d - Ainda eu simplificaria tudo para uma função só tipo `onclick=atualiza(1)` e `onclick=atualiza(-1)` - algo assim https://pastebin.com/sJkU4xXp

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco, com a função "updateColor" consegui o objetivo que queria, realmente não tinha pensado desta forma, executar a função dentro de outra.

Answer (score -4):

```js
var currentNumberWhapper = document.getElementById('currentNumber');
var currentNumber = 0;

function incremento() {
currentNumber = currentNumber + 1
currentNumberWhapper.innerHTML = currentNumber
currentNumberWhapper.textContent > 0 ? currentNumberWhapper.style.color = "black" : currentNumberWhapper.style.color = "red";
}
function decremento() {
currentNumber = currentNumber - 1
currentNumberWhapper.innerHTML = currentNumber
currentNumberWhapper.textContent > 0 ? currentNumberWhapper.style.color = "black" : currentNumberWhapper.style.color = "red";

}
```

```html
<body>

     <h1>Contador</h1>
     <p>Clique nos botões para alterar o valor.</p>

     <div class="contador">
         <button name="adicionar" onclick="incremento()">+</button>
                <p id="currentNumber">0</p> 
         <button name="subtrair" onclick="decremento()">-</button>
     </div>
     <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```